# How to Parse this Full Swagger 2.0 Schema Into JSON

Tags: json, swagger-2.0

The full schema here is too large for program we are using and need to break up. Looking for way to make say GetAccountBalance module and create its own schema. Schema Editor validates full as a good schema.

Parsed using the full JSON file, getting invalid schema regardless of how try.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/APIs-guru/openapi-directory/master/APIs/amazonaws.com/mturk-requester/2017-01-17/swagger.yaml

Comment: What parser/tool do you use? How did you create a "full JSON file" from this YAML file?

Comment: editor.swagger.io

Comment: Id be interested in just GetAccountBalance. I'm not understanding what needs to constitute the headers, and maybe footers for this.